# Test connection of h2 database

Tags: h2

I tried to test the connection on h2 console and got this error:-

[image]

The error with code 50000 is thrown when something unexpected occurs, for example an internal stack overflow. For details about the problem, see the cause of the exception in the stack trace.`[General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read the page at position 6322192528771 [1.4.200/6]" [50000-200] HY000/50000 (Help)][1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database file is corrupted. If you need data from it, you can try to use the recovery tool. If you don't need it, you can simply delete `test1.mv.db` in the home directory of your user account.

When you use persistent embedded databases in H2 you should be careful with them, `Thread.interrupt()` may corrupt the database file, for example, unless you're using the `async:` filesystem. Corruption is also possible when you open the database file from a recent version of H2 with older one. The default MVStore engine also has some own problems.